# looking for flabby sheaf resolutions

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, homology-cohomology, sheaf-theory, d-modules

I am looking for manipulable flabby resolution of the sheaf of top-degree forms (let say on a complex manifold $X$) which is not canonical, i.e. not the Godement resolution.

Does it exist any reference on the subject ?

beyond ring sheaf addendum: does a flabby resolution of the simplest D-module $D_{X}$ is known ?